# ASP.Net Web Application: How can I save my file to a client machine, (at a location specified by me), on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been scouring the web for a while for an answer to this one... would be fantastic if someone could help...

I need a button which saves a file contained within my web application to a location on a client machine. I would like this to be done simply on a button-click, i.e. without the user being prompted for anything such as a saving location.

I have found a way to do the save part of it, but only if it is the user who uploads the file:

```
.aspx file:
<button onserverclick="SaveButton_Click" runat="server"></button>

// Handles the uploading.
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>



.aspx.cs file:
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    // Creates a directory which will be deleted later.
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\temp");

    // Uploads the user's file to the new directory.
    this.FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\temp\\" + this.FileUpload1.FileName);
}
```

So my question is, how can I change this code from taking the user's uploaded file to taking my file saved in a folder within my application, (e.g. saved at "_resources/files/temp.txt")?

If it isn't obvious, this isn't exactly my forte. Thanks very much!

Comment: You want to save the same file in your website's folder ?

Comment: No, the file already exists in my website. I want to take that file and save it in a folder on the user's machine when they click the button.

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: The issue is that currently I'm taking a file that has been uploaded by the user, and saving that file to a location on the user's computer. I don't want to save a file uploaded by the user... I want to save a file that is present in my web application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anyway, but I've just found an answer:

```
.aspx file:
<button onserverclick="SaveButton_Click" runat="server"></button>

.aspx.cs file:
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    // Creates a directory which will be deleted later.
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\temp");

    // Creates the file I want to save, rather than having it in a location in my web application.
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create("C:\\temp\\temp.txt"))
    {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("This is some text in the file.");
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
}
```